# Asp.Net WebForms redirect without master page refresh

Tags: asp.net, iframe, single-page-application, master-pages

first thing, I know that the above desire is not possible due to the fact the the master page is part of the page. But I would like to create some kind of single page application where the child pages can access controls inside the master page and that on redirecting the master page is not reloaded. This is needed because I have a websocket connection in my master page that I need on every page, if I redirect to another page the connection is lost and reopened.

My thoughts were

1. iframes: No access to the outside lying controls
2. object tag: At the end it is an iframe
3. MasterPage: Page reloads on redirects

Comment: Correcting first point: you can access javascript functions over an iframe with window.parent if it is the same domain. Also you could bundle all scripts and add them also to the iframe. The Browser cache would handle duplicate server requests. Will post a solution later...